# Customising RStudio Theme for RMarkdown and Bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, themes, rstudio, bookdown

I use the theme *Solarized Dark* on RStudio. I'm writing lecture notes using `RMarkdown`/`bookdown`. I like it in general, but there is one issue I have with it:

> it colours all quotes, overriding most of the other colours.

Hopefully the following picture illustrates this.

[image]

I am writing maths lecture notes, so I use $...$ a lot. It's annoying to have it all the same colour, with only the emphasised text or footnotes standing out.

> Can I customise the theme so that writing `>` doesn't make this switch?
>
> Eg, in VSCode, the `>` is coloured green, but then nothing after it is coloured.

I've had a look at customising the themes, but haven't found how to do this. I can change the colour, or even delete the colour for `string`, but then everything is the plain white colour, including stuff between `$...$`. I want `>` not to overwrite the other highlighting.

An alternative solution, which I'd be very happy with would be to define some wrapper to make this go in a quote. The LaTeX equivalent would be the following.

[image]

This last part seems like much more of a big deal, but would be helpful as I wouldn't have to keep writing `>` for multi-line quotes.

Comment: Have you tried the RStudio visual editor? It shows you the math preview directly in the editor, which is way better experience than displaying the `$ $` source.

Comment: `:grimace:` no, thank you :P I write almost all my stuff in LaTeX. You may feel it's a "way better experience" and it's great that it works for you, but it certainly is not for me

Comment: [Please do take `:grimace:` in good jest! I realise you are the mighty YihuiXie themself, fabled bookdown-mastermind. I so appreciate that you've made lecture notes in Markdown a possibility!]

Comment: Haha, no problem! I used to think that LyX was the best LaTeX/math editor until RStudio visual markdown editor was able to preview math (it still can't beat LyX, but good enough for me).

Comment: @YihuiXie There are some people who will only do things on the command line, not using any GUI assistance. I always say how they shouldn't be so stuck in their ways and should utilise new tools, even if they're different. Of course, *those people* are silly for sticking to that. The same *couldn't possibly* be true for *me*, sticking with viewing the source rather than the preview. *They're* stick-in-the-muds; *I'm* sensible! `;)`

Comment: Totally understood :)